# Cannot redirect a JSP file and display values using Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, post-redirect-get

I have created a simple program that gets the firstname and lastname of a user using a textfield. But the problem is that when I click the submit button I cannot redirect it to another jsp file which shows the firstname and lastname of the user.

**Here's my `HelloAction` class:**

```
package com.novamsc.training.struts.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    public String user(){
        return "hello";
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public String display(){
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

**Here's my `userInput.jsp` file:**

```jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>User Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <s:form name="inputData">
    <s:textfield key="firstName"/>
    <s:textfield key="lastName"/>
    <s:submit/>
    </s:form>

</body>

</html>
```

**Here's my `resultInput.jsp` file:**

```java
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Get Result</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
    <s:property value="firstName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <s:property value="lastName" />
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

**Here's my `struts-traning.xml` file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <package name="hello" namespace="/exercise" extends="training-default">

        <action name="userInput" class="com.novamsc.training.struts.action.HelloAction"
            method="user">
            <result name="hello">/jsp/userInput.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="inputData" class="com.novamsc.training.struts.action.HelloAction"
            method="display">
            <result name="hi">/jsp/resultInput.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

Comment: Form submitted by default to the same action. If you need to redirect to another action after the form is submitted then you should use redirect result type or better redirect action result type.

Comment: can you please show me how?

Comment: I have shown you how, if this is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use form tag with additional attributes that map the form to another action.

```
<s:form name="inputData" namespace="/exercise" action="submitData">
    <s:textfield key="firstName"/>
    <s:textfield key="lastName"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

then for additional action you need to write action config

```
<action name="submitData" class="com.novamsc.training.struts.action.HelloAction"
            method="save">
            <result type="redirectAction">inputData</result>
</action>
```

add additional method to map the new action

```
public String save(){
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

---

This additional action is required to follow [PRG (Post-Redirect-Get)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.