# Modify record using Struts2

Tags: html, forms, struts2, struts

I have a table with a list of shows, my idea is to have a button that allows modifying each show:

```
         ...

         <s:iterator value="%{listShow}" var="show">
            <tr>
                <td><s:property value="showId"></s:property></td>
                <td><s:property value="showName"></s:property></td>
                <td><s:property value="showDate"></s:property></td>
                <td><s:property value="showPrice"></s:property></td>
                 <td><s:form action="goModify">
                        <s:submit value="Modify"></s:submit>
                        <s:hidden name="showId"></s:hidden>
                        <s:hidden name="showName"></s:hidden>
                        <s:hidden name="showDate"></s:hidden>
                        <s:hidden name="showPrice"></s:hidden>
                    </s:form></td>

            </tr>
        </s:iterator>


        ...
```

The only thing action "goModify" does is redirect to a modify.jsp file where I want to make the data changes:

```
    <s:form action="modifyAction">

        <s:textfield label="ID" name="showId" value="%{showId}"></s:textfield>
        <s:textfield label="Show Name" name="showName" value="%{showName}></s:textfield>
        <s:textfield label="Date" name="showDate" value="%{showDate}></s:textfield>
        <s:textfield label="Price" name="showPrice"value="%{showPrice}></s:textfield>

        <s:submit value="Modificar"></s:submit>

   </s:form>
```

The problem that the filled fields do not appear to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44616323/573032

Answer (score 0):

You are only assigning a name to the hidden fields, not a value. You can use the attribute `key` instead of `name`. It will automatically generate HTML with the correct name and value.

```
<s:iterator value="%{listShow}" var="show">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="showId" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="showName" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="showDate" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="showPrice" /></td>
        <td>
            <s:form action="goModify">
                <s:submit value="Modify" />
                <s:hidden key="showId" />
                <s:hidden key="showName" />
                <s:hidden key="showDate" />
                <s:hidden key="showPrice" />
            </s:form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

If the action goModify does not store the parameters in the value stack (e. g. by storing them in attributes), you may have to change the JSP to access the request parameters directly.

```
<s:form action="modifyAction">
    <s:textfield label="ID" name="showId" value="%{#parameters.showId}" />
    <s:textfield label="Show Name" name="showName" value="%{#parameters.showName} />
    <s:textfield label="Date" name="showDate" value="%{#parameters.showDate} />
    <s:textfield label="Price" name="showPrice" value="%{#parameters.showPrice} />
    <s:submit value="Modificar"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

However, the best solution for the second JSP would also be to use `key` instead of `name` and `value`. But then you have to make sure to have the values on the value stack.